# PHP - Task scheduler unable to include previous directories?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks

**The script that is scheduled:**

```
@echo off
D:\Servers\WebServer\php\php.exe -f D:\Servers\WebServer\htdocs\test\test.php
pause
```

When I run this script I get the following kind of errors:

```
include(../db/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Servers\WebServer\htdocs\test\test.php on line 2
```

Anything that seems to be a previous directory and contains ../ it doesn't seem to be able to find, and this is a very big problem for me.

I know the script works perfectly as I have tested it in browser without any issues.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: What is the output of **echo getcwd();** when executing in the test.php?

Comment: Nothing will even output with that command, I just tried it

Comment: You should use absolute paths when using include/require ie. `require_once __DIR__ . '/../db/db.php';` or `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../db/db.php';`